# Multiple like conditions from another table with XML

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an audit table set up with this kind of output (I have no say on the design) with the date, user, and column 'Record' (XML output)

| User | Date | Record |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-01 | see below couldn't input into this table |
| A1 | 2023-01-03 | see below couldn't input into this table |

```xml
<updated>
  <ID>322ZZ444-4B0A-3A28-8CF3-0T1ZC8D4D1CB</ID>
    <STATUS_ID>
      <old>2</old>
      <new>1</new>
    </STATUS_ID>

<updated>
  <ID>456AA241-7C1B-4L18-0AH4-7C1B7C1B7C1B </ID>
  <STATUS_ID>
    <old>2</old>
    <new>4</new>
  </STATUS_ID>
  <STATUS_DT>
    <old>2023-11-04</old>
    <new>2023-11-08</new>
  </STATUS_DT>
  <STUDENT_ID>
    <old>17</old>
    <new />
  </STUDENT_ID>
</updated>
```

The XML can be any length and have other variables in it

From another table B, I have the table as such:

| ID | Status_ID | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 322ZZ444-4B0A-3A28-8CF3-0T1ZC8D4D1CB | 1 | 4 |
| 456AA241-7C1B-4L18-0AH4-7C1B7C1B7C1B | 1 | 4 |
| 4B0A4B0A-4B0A-4B0A-4B0A-4B0A7C1B4B0A | 2 | 4 |

I want to find all the instances of the user and date from table B in table Audit. There are about 100 entries, the only way I can think of is to use an OR statement.

Right now it would need to be something such as:

```
select * from Audit table where 
cast(record as NVARCHAR(MAX)) like '%322ZZ444-4B0A-3A28-8CF3-0T1ZC8D4D1CB%' 
OR cast(record as NVARCHAR(MAX)) like '%456AA241-7C1B-4L18-0AH4-7C1B7C1B7C1B%'
```

But this seems unwieldly for 100 rows. Ideally I wish I could so something with the like or in but multiple values aren't allowed in the like statement and in statement requires exact values (which I don't have as I don't know what else was done).

```
select * from Audit table where 
cast(record as NVARCHAR(MAX)) like (select id from Table B where priority=4 and status_id=1)
```

Maybe I would need to loop through the values one by one in Table B and insert them into another table? (hypothetically seems like that would work but I don't know how)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL XQuery for this

```sql
SELECT *,
  a.Record.value('(updated/ID/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS ID
FROM Audit a
WHERE a.Record.value('(updated/ID/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') IN (
    SELECT B.ID
    FROM B
    WHERE B.priority = 4
      AND B.status_id = 1
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/xsYJm5qE)

Comment: I can't get this to work. My XML will have various tags (I won't know the extent unless I run them one by one). For example, 1 entry might have the tags of Status_id, but another might have 5 other entry tags. I think this limits to the first 100 characters?

Comment: No it limits the possible length of the `ID` node text that is being retrieved. If you give a fuller example, showing what possible XML nodes you might want to parse, we can give a better version of this. I can only go off what you show me. Note that the above code still works if you only have one `updated/ID` node in each row.